# 2011 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2011 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://gis.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: I notice that *pro-tem* mods @scw and @matt wilkie have the most badges on meta, top-ten overall reputations, are also in the top ten for voters and editors, ask good questions, and their tag counts exhibit broad interests.  Hint, hint :-).

Comment: I nominate @underdark and @whuber - but added @mapperz on the http://gis.stackexchange.com/election if anyone wants to vote for them.

Comment: I support Mapperz suggestion and whuber's...but the nomination process seems to put me in an endless loop...is there a reputation minimum?  If not, forward my nominations accordingly.

Comment: @Dan Nominating others is purely a political exercise: it has no actual effect.  Individuals must formally nominate themselves in order to become candidates.  The most we can accomplish here is to supply a certain amount of ... persuasion.

Comment: @Dan: The reputation minimum is just 300 pts according to the nomination page.

Comment: +1 for @whuber!

Comment: +1 for @underdark!

Answer (score 9):

**I would like to encourage community members of even modest reputation to consider becoming candidates for moderator**.  Although many of the highest-rep members in GIS are qualified, high total reputation is not a necessity for being a good moderator.  Among the qualities that may (IMHO) be better indicators of moderator candidates are:

- **Balanced** participation: a broad range of interests, as reflected in tag counts.
- **High-quality** answers, as reflected (partly) by average votes per answer and rate at which answers are accepted.
- **Graciousness** in formulating replies and comments.
- Some participation in the **meta** site.
- Extensive **voting**, with judicious (but sparing) amounts of downvoting.
- **Regular participation** over several months (at least), suggesting a knowledge of the community and how it works and personal commitment to it.

If you have most of these qualities, please consider nominating yourself.

Incidentally, geographic location is important.  It helps when the mods can span all time zones during their working days, because then there's always at least one around to respond.  Did I read somewhere that we have some Tasmanians? :-)

Comment: +1 for covering all timezones

Comment: @Mapperz If you're actually located where your gravatar indicates, then you have all time zones covered at once!

Comment: 50/50 (6 months each side of the Atlantic)